# как остановить QGraphicsItem::update

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

Наследуюсь от `QGraphicsItem`. Рисую на низком уровне фигуру, переопределив

```
void paint(*painter, const *option, QWidget *)
```

и

```
QRectF boundingRect()
```

занося эту фигуру на сцену при помощи `addItem`.

И вот этот пользовательский `item` постоянно потом перерисовывается (то есть, срабатывает `paint`). при добавлении других новых элементов на сцену .

Как я понимаю, происходит постоянно `update()`. А этот `update` невозможно отключить? Фигура ведь отрисована, закреплена или же нет, и  она хранится в виде того что описано в paint ?

Comment: Вроде два варианта. Либо отключать [`ItemSendsGeometryChanges`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlag), так как он по дефолту стоит, и возможно триггерит перерисовку при добавлении новых элементов, больше вроде нечему триггерить. Либо отключить [`QGraphicsView::setUpdatesEnabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#updatesEnabled-prop), что полностью отключит обновление и тогда надо будет явно вызывать `update()`.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @DiMithras
а можете ещё проконсультировать ? А то не разобрался .  Вот эта функция "boundingRect()" она определяет как раз границы что надо апдейтить или же у неё другая функция ?*

Comment: @АндрейГуренков Оформите это как новый вопрос. SO, все же, не совсем (или совсем не) форум.

Comment: @Юрий Козлов последнее что хотел спросить и всё. прям такой строгач тут ) ну ладно сделаю как скажете

Comment: @АндрейГуренков Если Вы оформите это, как новый вопрос, то кто-то, кому эта информация может быть полезна, сможет ее найти. А если продолжить обсуждение в комментариях, то...... Ну, может, кому и повезет, но шансов мало. Вот поэтому и срогач - чтобы было проще найти информацию.

Comment: @Юрий Козлов, ладно, ладно. не спорю . сделаю

Comment: Да @ЮрийКозлов всё верно пишет. Цель портала создать что-то вроде википедии по ИТ тематике, поэтому строгие правила к оформлению вопросов, тегов, ответов, и к комментариям. Так то мы добрые, и готовы хоть в чат уйти, но специфика `boundingRect()` немного за контекстом, поэтому лучше в новый вопрос.